# C# - Share Types Between Modular Parts Of Application

Tags: c#, types, dependency-injection, share, modularity

*(This is not about modularity between assemblies but about modularity between simple C# classes/objects)*

---

My application (`C#`) can be divided into following parts:

- **components** (display results and stuff)
- **worker classes** that do some work (other thread than any form or component)
- **main form** (agent between components and worker classes using events and delegates)

components and worker classes don't have any `using` dependencies to any other namespace or class except the ones from the Framework.

---

Now I can't use Framework types anymore. I need custom classes. How do I share my custom types between those parts of the application without breaking up the modularity ? What are the common techniques ?

---

**Edit:**

- I'm trying to use simple types like `int`, `float`, `string`, `Point`, `PointF` and arrays of all of them. But now I need to add time stamps, quality values, ...
- can't convert them because the data handled by the components is big and good performance is a must-have

Comment: At some level or other you have to use framework types (string,int,byte,double) - so what Framework types are you trying to remove references to?

Comment: "Now I can't use Framework types anymore. I need custom classes.". Why is that?

Comment: I still don't get it. Why do those framework types are in the way of good performance?

Comment: @Steven Because they are not. No one said that.

Comment: "How do I share my custom types between those parts of the application" : what are these types for ? Between which parts ? In what direction ? Sharing implies a source and consumers - what would they be ?